# Dozer mapping issue with 1:1 conversion

Tags: dozer

I'm getting this error while mapping these two fields.  I've looked for documentation on how to map this from one object to the other, but there's very few documentation for the data type DurationImpl.  The 1:1 mapping should be the same object type, but for some reason dozer isnt picking this up.  Is there a way to override the source to the javax.xml.datatype.Duration type?

```
main ERROR org.dozer.MappingProcessor(283) - Field mapping error -->
      MapId: null
      Type: null
      Source parent class: com.aa.flighthub.services.flightinfo.operational.messages.Times
      Source field name: autoETDAccumMins
      Source field type: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DurationImpl
      Source field value: PT0S
      Dest parent class: com.aa.matrix.flightinfo.types.flightinfo.v1.Times
      Dest field name: autoETDAccumMins
      Dest field type: javax.xml.datatype.Duration
```

Comment: The error says "Source field value: PT0S". The documentation for the destination field (javax.xml.datatype.Duration) says "A Duration object represents a period of Gregorian time, which consists of six fields (years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds) plus a sign (+/-) field." Any chance the problem is in the content of the data in the autoETDAccumMins instance?

Comment: I do not believe so, I think the content is valid.  I put in a different value "-P0DT6H0M0S" that is similar to the format provided, and it comes up with the same mapping error.  Thanks for the help btw!

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally figured out the error, so I implemented a custom dozer mapping to map this particular class.  Once mapped using that method, the mapping went fine.  Hopefully this helps someone in the future.